# IdentityServer3: Dependency Injection with RegistrationMode.InstancePerHttpRequest

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, identityserver3

I am implementing a IdentityServer3 and want to use a custom IUserService to check against our user table in our database.

Our server handles more than one database (or "tenants"), so the database context is always different per HttpRequest.

```
var factory = new IdentityServerServiceFactory();
factory.UserService = new Registration<IUserService>(resolver => new MyUserService(resolver.Resolve<IDatabaseInstance>()));
```

So i want to use a dependency registation per HTTP-request.
I think this is the desired setting:
IdentityServer3.Core.Configuration.RegistrationMode.InstancePerHttpRequest

But how can I use this?
The neccessary database is not known on boot-time in the StartUp-class.

I know the database within the ApiController. So I would like to requester the IDatabaseInstance there.
Can I do this? How can I do this?

Is there an example?
This is not helping, because it covers only simple scenarios...
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/DependencyInjection